# Keep a column from a dataframe matrix

Tags: r

Using this dataframe as input

```
employee <- c('JohnDoe','PeterGynn','laughter','laughter','happiness')
filename <- c('myfile_1','myfile_1','myfile_1','myfile_2','myfile_2')
input <- data.frame(employee, filename)

employee filename
JohnDoe myfile_1
PeterGynn myfile_1
laughter myfile_1
laughter myfile_2
happiness myfile_2
```

It is possible using the following have a binary representation of what exist or not:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(input)))
 happiness JohnDoe laughter PeterGynn
myfile_1         0       1        1         1
myfile_2         1       0        1         0
```

How is it possible to have a column for myfile names inside to be the number of rows and when save the result into csv they don't exist?

Comment: The `as.data.frame.matrx` is a `data.frame`.  Not clear about your question.  can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun please see the table of the results I added. The myfile_1, myfile_2 it is possible to see but the don't have a column name and if you save the new df into a csv you will see it is not exist.

Comment: We can have `library(tibble);as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(input))) %>% rownames_to_column('rn')`  Also, in `write.csv`, you can have `row.names = TRUE`

Comment: @akrun is it helpful now? What I want is to have the row name as a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the rownames as column, then `rownames_to_column` from `tibble` can be used

```
library(tibble)
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(input))) %>% 
                       rownames_to_column('rn')
#        rn happiness JohnDoe laughter PeterGynn
#1 myfile_1         0       1        1         1
#2 myfile_2         1       0        1         0
```

---

It can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
input %>%
     count(employee, filename) %>% 
     spread(employee, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 2
#filename happiness JohnDoe laughter PeterGynn
#* <fctr>       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 myfile_1      0       1.00     1.00      1.00
#2 myfile_2      1.00    0        1.00      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you have saved the data as follows:

```
> d <- as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(input)))
```

Then you can easily access the rownames and save it to a new column:

```
> d['rowname'] <- rownames(d)
> d
         happiness JohnDoe laughter PeterGynn  rowname
myfile_1         0       1        1         1 myfile_1
myfile_2         1       0        1         0 myfile_2
```

Then, when saving, it saves these column too and after reading in you of course can again set the row names / index via

```
 rownames(d) <- d['rowname']
```